# Migrating from QWebKitWidgets to QWebEngineWidgets with project file supporting both

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

I am currently adding support of QWebEngineWidgets to my older applications but I don't want to loose QWebKitWidgets. because in some embeded platforms the qt version is still 5.3. I wonder if the following solution I made by myself is correct and better solutions is also welcome.

```
equals(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5) {
    lessThan(QT_MINOR_VERSION, 5) {
        QT += webkitwidgets
    }
    greaterThan(QT_MINOR_VERSION, 4) {
        QT += webenginewidgets
    }
}
```

Comment: alternatively you could consider using https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit on newer versions

Comment: wow, I have n't seen this before. webkit was quite sth that webengine could not replace it. you could almost parse html tags with webkit one by one. I hope it ported back to qt with this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use "else" for the alternative branch, e.g.

```
lessThan(QT_MINOR_VERSION, 5) {
} else {
}
```

or even check for a module's availability specifically

```
qtHaveModule(webengine) {
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the else with  qtHaveModule block and is there a relevant to this macro in cpp source code. e.g. sth we could use with #if

Comment: Yes, you can use an else with that.
I am not sure if there is a standard define, but you can always set your own defines in the `.pro` file, e.g: `DEFINES += HAVE_WEBENGINE` and then check for it in your code: `#ifdef HAVE_WEBENGINE`